# How do you convert QString to a QString pointer?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

Convert QString to a QString pointer?
I have this method that returns a Qstring

```
QString Redis:test()
{
return (QString) "Im Testing"
}
```

Called in a class that needs to assign the returning value to a pointer

```
QString* Test::connectRedis()
{
Redis* db = new Redis(this);
QString* testing =  db->test();
return testing;
}
```

The error Im getting :

```
 error: no viable conversion from 'QString' to 'QString *'
```

Comment: `(QString) "Im Testing"` is crazy! Write `QString("Im Testing")`. Your syntax is a c-style cast while you want to call the QString-constructor. In your case calling `return "Im Testing"` would also work, as the QString constructor is called implicitly.

Comment: In terms of your question: Please read a book on C++. What you are asking are C++ basics. Without those basics you will shoot yourself into the foot sooner than later, as C++ is very complex, combined with few safety guarnatees. For example with the existing answer you have to manage memory yourself, or otherwise it will leak. `db` leaks in your code.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted ? This is a Q and A site.

Comment: It was downvoted because your code shows a lack of basic understanding of C++. Which can be obtained via google and is not the focus of this site. This is not a tutorial website.

Comment: @BetaCarotin I don't think implicit sharing in QT has to do anything with fundamental understanding of C++ or tutorials. You should toss away your naive assumption that everyone here is a QT guru and you should understand that people that are trying to learn come to StackOverflow for guidance.  Further, there are questions here on StackOverFlow that are unarguably more beginner then this one.

Comment: Implicit sharing in QT is indeed not fundamental C++. I did not claim that. But c-style casting a c-string to a class, and implicitly converting from `QString` to `QString*` *ARE* fundamental mistakes. Also, I myself am not a Qt guru. I have hardly used it at all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows lack of research and of fundamentals of the language being used. Stack Overflow is not a language tutorial site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
QString* Test::connectRedis()
{
    Redis* db = new Redis(this);
    return new QString(db->test());
}
```

That being said, Qt's classes use [implicit sharing](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/implicit-sharing.html), so returning a `QString` pointer like this isn't really necessary.  Just return a copy of the `QString`.